# error when evaluate InterpolationFunction

Tags: interpolation

### Problem

I'd like to plot a moving point along zig zag line. And I used interpolation function to describe the zig zag line.

However when plotting the moving point, there is something wrong with evaluating the interpolation function. My codes is as bellow:

```
list3d = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 3}]
d3tube = Graphics3D[{Red, Tube[list3d, .04]}]
f = Interpolation[Table[{i, list3d[[i]]}, {i, 0, 10}]] 
DynamicModule[{t},
 DynamicWrapper[
  Show[d3tube, Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Black, Point[f[t]]}]],t = Clock[{0, 10}]]
 ]           (*erro occurs!*)
```

### Diagnosing

I examine the evaluation of interpolation function with bellowed codes:

```
Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, 0, 10, 0.05}]
```

which output:

> {{0., {1.45643 - 1. (0. - 1. (-1.45643 + List)), 8.55359 - 1. (0. - 1. (-8.55359 + List)), 5.97185 - 1. (0. - 1. (-5.97185 + List))}}, {0.05, {1.45643 - 0.95 (0.05 (-0.975 (0.333333 (-6.98393 - 0.5 (8.81651 - List)) - 1. (0.5 (8.81651 - List) + 1. (-1.45643 + List))) + 1. (0.5 (8.81651 - List) + 1. (-1.45643 + List))) - 1. (-1.45643 + List)),
>   ......

It shows there's `List` symbol within the output, I think, which mess up the `Evaluation of Interpolation`.

### Question

Can any one figure out how to evaluate the `interpolation` correctly to generate  the coordinates of moving point?

Comment: Hint: Something's wrong with the interpolating function, i.e. `f`.  The first thing to do is test `f` separately. Try `f[0]`. What does it give?  You'll see that it's not a number and that it has `List` in it. Why `List`? `List` is just a head of an expression. The head is *the element with index 0*. Once you realize this, you will look at the `Table` function and notice that the iterator `i`, which is also used as an array index with `Part`, goes from `0`, and not from `1`!  There's your problem.

Comment: You will have to adjust the range in `Clock` accordingly. And there's another problem: the first argument of DynamicWrapper won't dynamically update unless it is wrapped in Dynamic. It will still see `t` as a symbol.  It will be better to use a single `Dynamic`.  For performance, put the `Point` in an `Epilog`, and make only the `Epilog` `Dynamic`. You can replace `t` with `Clock[...]` directly, and get rid of `t`. You may also want to use `InterpolationOrder -> 1` to move along line segments.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about Epilog, it doesn't take 3D graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
list3d = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 3}];
d3tube = Graphics3D[{Red, Tube[list3d, .04]}];
f = Interpolation[Table[{i, list3d[[i]]}, {i, 1, 10}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Show[d3tube, 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Black, 
   Dynamic@Point[f[Clock[{1, 10}]]]}]]
```

Changes:

- Mathematica uses 1-based indexing. Start from 1, not from 0.
- Use `Dynamic` instead of `DynamicWrapper`. Wrap it only around the bit where it is necessary, to improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
r = {x, y, z} = Transpose[list3d];
{xi, yi, zi} = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] & /@ r;
if[t_] := {xi[t], yi[t], zi[t]};
Animate[Graphics3D[{Red, Tube[list3d, .04], PointSize[Large], Black, 
   Point[if[t]]}], {t, 1, 10}]
```

[image]